# convert vue 2 to vue 3 with oruga-next -- can't use v-model with o-switch and watch

Tags: node.js, vue.js, migration, vuejs3, watch

I am trying to port an application from vue 2 to vue 3. I have problems. I'm not sure if the problems are the 'v-model' in the template, or the 'watch' command in the script area. This is a vue file.

```
    <template>
      <div class="home notification is-primary">
        <o-field>

          <o-switch  v-model="isSwitched" >
            Audio: {{ isSwitched }} 
          </o-switch>
            </div>
    </template>

    <script>


    export default {
      name: "HomeInput",
      props: {
        setAudio: Function,
      },
      data() {
        return {
          isSwitched:true,
        };
      },
      methods: {
      },
      mounted: function () {
      },

      watch:  {
        'isSwitched' (val) {
            console.log(val,  "switch");
            this.setAudio(val);
        }
      },
    };
    </script>

    <style scoped>
    </style>
```

I never get 'switch' in the console, though I can see the component switch on the screen. Below is part of my package.json. I use oruga-ui for the vue components like 'o-switch'.

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.18.6",
    "@babel/core": "^7.18.6",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.18.6",
    "@google-cloud/speech": "^4.10.0",
    "@oruga-ui/oruga-next": "^0.5.5",
    "@vue/babel-preset-app": "^5.0.7",
    "@vue/cli": "^5.0.7",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^5.0.7",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "^5.0.7",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-router": "^5.0.7",
    "@vue/cli-service": "^5.0.7",
    "@vue/compat": "^3.1.0-0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.5",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "browser-request": "^0.3.3",
    "browserify-fs": "^1.0.0",
    "bulma": "^0.9.4",
    "vue": "^3.2.37",
    "vue-loader": "^17.0.0",
    "vue-router": "^4.1.1",
    "webpack": "^5.73.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.10.0"
  },
```

Comment: I cannot [reproduce the problem](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-vite-starter-nuhp5d?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FHomeInput.vue).

Comment: I notice that the code you use does not have "vue/compat". I tried to remove this from my project and got the following error about not being able to find vue.


     ERROR  Failed to compile with 4 errors                                                                                                                                            10:23:14 AM

     error  in ./src/App.vue?vue&type=template&id=8128415a

    Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'vue' in '/home/dave/workspace/electron-gpt/src'